# Push and Pull tags to organize different complex layouts

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a webpage where I want to organize the different hierarchy levels on the page as the Bootstrap responsive media queries kick in.

Currently I am working with the items in a `container > row > col-x-y` setup. As you will see in the code provided, I have a mock up of the actual website.

The goal is to get the order of these items in different places as the page changes size. The way I set up this code will show the different screen size layouts. [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cyberbit/cdy98m1z/) with the code below.

I have heard of a way to use Push and Pull in the `col` tags but I don't know if I quite understand how it works. So here are my questions:

1) Is this possible?

2) If so, can it properly do this layout?

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.well {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Items with an * are the ones that move</h2>

  <h3>Smallest screens</h3>
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <div class="well">
        <b>Picture Carousel</b>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <div class="well">
        <b>*Get Help</b>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <div class="well">
        <b>*Current Status</b>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <div class="well">
        <b>Column item 1</b>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <div class="well">
        <b>Column item 2</b>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <div class="well">
        <b>Column item 3</b>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <div class="well">
        <b>Calendar Items Static Carousel</b>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <div class="well">
        <b>*Stay Connected</b>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>


  <h3>Small screens</h3>
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <div class="well">
        <b>Picture Carousel</b>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <div class="well">
        <b>*Get Help</b>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <div class="well">
        <b>*Current Status</b>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <div class="well">
        <b>Column item 1</b>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <div class="well">
        <b>Column item 2</b>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <div class="well">
        <b>Column item 3</b>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
      <div class="well">
        <b>Calendar Items Static Carousel</b>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
      <div class="well">
        <b>*Stay Connected</b>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  

  <h3>Medium and Large Screens screens</h3>
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
      <div class="well">
        <b>Picture Carousel</b>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <div class="well">
        <b>*Current Status</b>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
      <div class="well">
        <b>*Get Help</b>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <div class="well">
        <b>*Stay Connected</b>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <div class="well">
        <b>Column item 1</b>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <div class="well">
        <b>Column item 2</b>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <div class="well">
        <b>Column item 3</b>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <div class="well">
        <b>Calendar Items Static Carousel</b>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the order between screen sizes absolutely critical to the solution?

Comment: Yes. That's the only part that I am really looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't look like the specific layout you want is possible with just Bootstrap grid classes. If you want I can rewrite my answer explaining _why_ it's not possible, otherwise I'll just mention that it's not. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Three different layouts by Bootstrap

1. I've duplicated the last block. (It is colored in red.)
2. I wrapped first and second block in one large block. And wrapped the third block and the duplicate of the last block in another large block. (Large blocks are blue.)

[image: Three different layouts by Bootstrap]

Please check the result: https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/2y08thn5/

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.well {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.well-red {
  background: #fcc;
}
.well-blue {
  background: #ccf;
  padding: 4px 4px 0;
  margin: -4px -4px 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Items with an * are the ones that move
  <br>The red block is duplicated</h2>

  <h3>Screen is 
    <span class="visible-xs-inline">smallest</span>
    <span class="visible-sm-inline">small</span>
    <span class="visible-md-inline">medium</span>
    <span class="visible-lg-inline">large</span>
  </h3>

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
      <div class="well well-blue">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="well">
              <b>Picture Carousel</b>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="well">
              <b>*Get Help</b>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="well well-blue">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="well">
              <b>*Current Status</b>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
            <div class="well well-red">
              <b>*Stay Connected</b>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <div class="well">
        <b>Column item 1</b>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <div class="well">
        <b>Column item 2</b>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <div class="well">
        <b>Column item 3</b>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-12">
      <div class="well">
        <b>Calendar Items Static Carousel</b>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 visible-xs visible-sm">
      <div class="well well-red">
        <b>*Stay Connected</b>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

---

### UPD. Duplicate the last block by jQuery

You can edit only one block and then clone it by jQuery.

https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/m1egqbm0/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( '#duplicate-this-block' ).clone().appendTo( "#put-a-duplicate-here" ).attr( 'class', 'col-md-12 hidden-xs hidden-sm' );
});
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.well {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.well-red {
  background: #fcc;
}
.well-blue {
  background: #ccf;
  padding: 4px 4px 0;
  margin: -4px -4px 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Items with an * are the ones that move
  <br>The red block is duplicated by jQuery</h2>

  <h3>Screen is 
    <span class="visible-xs-inline">smallest</span>
    <span class="visible-sm-inline">small</span>
    <span class="visible-md-inline">medium</span>
    <span class="visible-lg-inline">large</span>
  </h3>

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
      <div class="well well-blue">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="well">
              <b>Picture Carousel</b>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="well">
              <b>*Get Help</b>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="well well-blue">
        <div id="put-a-duplicate-here" class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="well">
              <b>*Current Status</b>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <div class="well">
        <b>Column item 1</b>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <div class="well">
        <b>Column item 2</b>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <div class="well">
        <b>Column item 3</b>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-12">
      <div class="well">
        <b>Calendar Items Static Carousel</b>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="duplicate-this-block" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 visible-xs visible-sm">
      <div class="well well-red">
        <b>*Stay Connected</b>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I didn't realize that I could just duplicate the code. Can you explain to me how the 2nd and 3rd items switch with each other?

Comment: @Tylersong55 I wrapped first and second block in one large block. And wrapped the third block and the duplicate of the last block in another large block.

Comment: @Tylersong55 I've colored blocks and added the explanation to my answer.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way that I can have the two Stay Connected items come from the same source and just have a tag that places them in their spots? It would be nice to be able to just edit the same area when it needs to change.

Comment: @Tylersong55 I've added [one more solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37642235/6263942) by using of the `order` property. But be careful about [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/order#Browser_compatibility)!

Comment: @Tylersong55 You can clone the last block using jQuery. I've added the code with jQuery into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I originally misunderstood the question, which is about [column ordering](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering). The original is below.

After much review and testing, **it doesn't look like what you want is possible.** Bootstrap organizes its grid into rows, and your requirements would need elements to jump across rows (something not possible without JavaScript).

---

This is possible using [offsetting columns](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting). I've added some CSS to the grid to make the effect more obvious. Click "Full page" to get a better view.

This is not a complete solution, but hopefully it can serve as a guide to help you towards your goal.

```css
.show-grid [class^=col-] {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #eee;
  background-color: rgba(86, 61, 124, .15);
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border: 1px solid rgba(86, 61, 124, .2);
}
.show-grid {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row show-grid">
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">.col-md-4 .col-md-offset-4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row show-grid">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3">.col-md-3 .col-md-offset-3</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3">.col-md-3 .col-md-offset-3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row show-grid">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">.col-md-6 .col-md-offset-3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't really help because I am trying to completely change the order of these sections. Notice that the second and third items switch places and the "Stay Connected" item goes from being last to fourth when going from smallest to biggest.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question. I'll take a second look.

Answer (score 0):

## Use flex to change the order of blocks

You can change the `order` property for colored blocks on medium and large screens.

But be careful about [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/order#Browser_compatibility)!

[image: Use flex to change order of blocks on medium amd large screens]

Please check the result: https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/cgog59ec/

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.well {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.flex-minus-1 .well { background: #fcc; }
.flex-minus-2 .well { background: #cfc; }
.flex-minus-3 .well { background: #ccf; }
.flex-minus-4 .well { background: #ffc; }

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .flex-md { 
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .flex-minus-1 { order: -1; } 
  .flex-minus-2 { order: -2; } 
  .flex-minus-3 { order: -3; } 
  .flex-minus-4 { order: -4; } 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Colored blocks are changing their "order" property</h2>

  <h3>Screen is 
    <span class="visible-xs-inline">smallest</span>
    <span class="visible-sm-inline">small</span>
    <span class="visible-md-inline">medium</span>
    <span class="visible-lg-inline">large</span>
  </h3>

  <div class="row flex-md">

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 flex-minus-4">
      <div class="well">
        <b>Picture Carousel</b>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 flex-minus-2">
      <div class="well">
        <b>*Get Help</b>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 flex-minus-3">
      <div class="well">
        <b>*Current Status</b>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <div class="well">
        <b>Column item 1</b>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <div class="well">
        <b>Column item 2</b>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <div class="well">
        <b>Column item 3</b>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-12">
      <div class="well">
        <b>Calendar Items Static Carousel</b>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 flex-minus-1">
      <div class="well">
        <b>*Stay Connected</b>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```